# Where is the "Conditional Build Symbols" option in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I've seen a lot of things about VS2015 mention this feature, where is it in VS2019?
In VS2015 it was under build options but I can't find it anywhere now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer, under project properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor there is an option called "Preprocessor Definitions" which was what I was looking for